# Console doesn't compile nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer, body-parser

I have a denwer local server and node.js 10.16.2. I have a main folder(with all files) and subfolder 'question'. There is file quest.js in 'question'. I send the POST request to the port 8001 from index.html file.

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var data = {}; 

app.listen(8001);

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    data = req.body;
    res.redirect('Z:/denwer/www/denwer/asksuccess/suc.html?name='+data.name);
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
          pass: 'mypassword'
        }
      });

      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'emails@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Вопрос по корсетам',
        html: 'Имя:'+data.name+'<br>Email:'+data.email+'<br>Телефон:'+data.telephon+'<br>Вопрос:<br><br>'+data.question
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
});
```

I wrote in the console: node quest.js but it hasn't given me any result. I waited for an empty output and new line but it hasn't compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write console.log('Working...') somewhere in the file to see if the file is being read. Also, you can pass a function to app.listen and add a console.log in there to see if the app is listening for requests. Something like

```
app.listen(8001, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 8001');
});
```